# PHP Regex match one letter and one number

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace any occurrences when you find a single letter followed by a single number in a string.

```
$word = 'AB001J1'; //or ZR010F2 or ZQ10B5

echo str_replace('/^(?=.*\pL)(?=.*\p{Nd})/', '', $word);
```

> Trying to get the result AB001 //or ZR010 or ZQ10

Comment: You "...want to replace any occurrence..." with what? An empty string? What do you mean by "single letter"? If you just mean "letter", say that, don't confuse readers by saying "single letter", suggesting it's something different than just a "letter".  If you mean something else be specific. I initially thought you meant neither `'J'` in `'JJ'` is a "single letter" because there are two in a row. Same with "single number". What about `"AB12C"`? Is that is to produce `"A2C"`? If so, I assume `"A2C"1` is not to then be changed to `"C"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex splitting approach works well here:

```php
$word = 'AB001J1';
$output = preg_split("/(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])/", $word, 2)[0];
echo $output;  // AB001
```

The above strategy is to split the input string at any point in between a digit and uppercase letter (in that order).  This separates the various terms, and we retain only the first one.